# Get bin width used for seaborn plot

Tags: python, seaborn

How do I find out what bin width was used when doing a distplot in Seaborn? I have two datasets I would like to share bin widhts, but don't know how to return the default value used for the first dataset. for something like the simple example below, how would I find out the bin width used?

```
import nump as np
import seaborn as sns
f, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
distribution=np.random.rand(1000)
sns.distplot(distribution, hist=True , kde_kws={"shade": True},ax=axs)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seaborn uses *Freedman-Diaconis rule* to calculate *bin width* if `bins` parameter is not specified in the function [`seaborn.distplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

The equation is as follows (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule)):

[image: Freedman-Diaconis rule]

We can calculate IQR and the cube-root of *n* with the following code.

```
Q1 = np.quantile(distribution, 0.25)
Q3 = np.quantile(distribution, 0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

cube = np.cbrt(len(distribution)
```

The *bin width* is:

```
In[] : 2*IQR/cube 
Out[]: 0.10163947994817446
```

Finally, we can now calculate the *number of bins*.

```
In[] : 1/(2*IQR/cube) # '1' is the range of the array for this example
Out[]: 9.838696543015526
```

When we round up the result, it amounts to 10. That's our number of bins. We can now specify `bins` parameter to get the same number of bins (or same bin width for the same range)

Graph w/o specifying bins:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
distribution=np.random.rand(1000)
sns.distplot(distribution, hist=True , kde_kws={"shade": True},ax=axs)
```

[image: Bin width for seaborn distplot]

Graph w/ specifying the parameter `bins=10`:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.distplot(distribution, bins=10, hist=True , kde_kws={"shade": True},ax=axs)
```

[image: Bin width]

**Update:**

Seaborn version 0.9 was mentioning *Freedman-Diaconis rule* as a way to calculate bin size:

> Specification of hist bins, or None to use Freedman-Diaconis rule.

The description changed in version 0.10 as follows:

> Specification of hist bins. If unspecified, as reference rule is used that tries to find a useful default.

Comment: This is a great answer. kudos!

Comment: Where did you find that seaborn uses that formula?  I'm running a histogram with 200k points and an IQR of around 2.7.  Your formula suggests there would be 11 bins, but I'm clearly seeing a few dozen.

Comment: It seems that the formula to calculate bin size is changed in version 0.10. You can check where they mention Freedman-Diaconis rule in version 0.9. from [this page](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Seaborn.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/seaborn.distplot.html).